# Making a node_module global using Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, webpack, webpack-2

I am using the below package on an angular project:

https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

A requirement is that it needs highcharts as a global dependency, in which it tells you to add a script tag into your html:

`<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>`

Rather than add the above script tag into my HTML I would like to make it global via Webpack.

I have installed highcharts via npm and have tried using the ProvidePlugin and the noParse methods described here (to no avail): https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#scripts-loader

For the ProvidePlugin option I used:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Highcharts: "highcharts",
})
```

for noParse:

```
noParse: [
  /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]highcharts[\/\\]highcharts\.js$/,
],
```

Neither worked, meaning when highcharts-ng tried to work, it gets an error because it cannot create a `new Highcharts`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined

// from highcharts-ng which throws above error
chart = new Highcharts[chartType](mergedOptions, func);
```

Here is my angular module

```
import angular from 'angular'
import highchartsNg from 'highcharts-ng'
import { ReportsData } from './reports.data'
import { reportsWidget } from './reports-widget/component'

export const ReportsModule = angular
  .module('reports', [
    highchartsNg,
  ])
  .factory('ReportsData', ReportsData)
  .component('reportsWidget', reportsWidget)
  .name
```

My webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app/modules',
  entry: {
    vendor: ['angular', 'highcharts-ng'],
    modules: './modules.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/.tmp/modules',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    // info: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['vendor', 'manifest'],
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { presets: ['es2015'] },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: I have added highcharts to my vendor bundle:
   vendor: ['angular', 'highcharts', 'highcharts-ng'],

also added:
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]highcharts[\/\\]highcharts\.js$/,
        loader: 'exports-loader?Highcharts',
      },
    ],

This isn't amending the file and I still have the problem. Is the above correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, my first link was to the wrong plugin :( . I meant the [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader). This allows you to define globally (on the window) available packages. Unfortuntaly, I'm not on the migration path to webpack 2 with this loader.

Answer (score 0):

Use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) and write `require('expose-loader?Highcharts!highcharts');` somewhere before the first usage of `Highcharts` global variable. This will require highcharts and save expose it as `window.Highcharts` in the browser.

Under the hood webpack makes it available for you as:

```
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(global) {module.exports = global["Highcharts"] = __webpack_require__(1);
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, __webpack_require__(2)))

/***/ }
```